# How to update state of nested array of array of objects without mutating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, state, setstate

I am tryin to update the state of nested array of objects, for instance add to results[0].rooms[2] -> loop rooms -> and add to each object room.sunday.flag

```
array of results:
results:  [ 
  { dates:
  { weekstart: 2018-08-26T04:00:00.000Z,
    weekend: 2018-09-02T03:59:59.000Z,
    daysofweek: [Array] },
 need: [ '103', '204', '12', '234', '34', '555', '44' ],
 backorder:
  [ '100', '102', '150', '403', '344', '12', '3434', '23', '44' ],
 _id: 5b7b139465c29145d8d69ac2,
 iscurrent: true,
 isnext: false,
 rooms: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
 user: 5b61b782719613486cdda7ec,
 __v: 9 },

 { dates:
  { weekstart: 2018-09-02T04:00:00.000Z,
    weekend: 2018-09-09T03:59:59.000Z,
    daysofweek: [Array] },
 need: [ '12', '13', '55', '45' ],
 backorder: [ '10', '11', '112' ],
 _id: 5b83fdc500b6b6dc493e9bb8,
 iscurrent: false,
 isnext: true,     rooms: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], 
 [Object] ],
 user: 5b61b782719613486cdda7ec,
 __v: 9 } 
 ]
```

my attempt to change the state without mutating

```
   const resultsRooms = [ 
     ...this.state.results[0].rooms ];
        const rooms = resultsRooms.map((room, roomIndex) => 
   {
        room.sunday.flag = true;
   });

   const resultsUpdaye = this.results.forEach((element, index) => {
      if (index === 0) {
            elsment.rooms = rooms;
         }
   });

   this.setState({
            results: resultsUpdaye
   });
```

any help? what am i doin wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `resultsRooms.map` is wrong. First of all, it does not return an object. If you use an arrow function and want to return an object, you must enclose it with parentheses.

```
const foo = () => ( { foo: "bar" } );
```

If you don't do that the function sees `{}` as a body block.

Your second problem is, `map` returns an array, does not do operations on items. So you can't do this: `room.sunday.flag = true;`

Here is the working version:

```
const rooms = resultsRooms.map((room, roomIndex) => 
   ( { ...room, sunday: {...room["sunday"], flag: true } } )
);
```

So, we map the rooms, then return an object with spread syntax. With `...room` we keep the parts of the `room` other than the `sunday` object. With `sunday: {...room["sunday"], flag: true }` we keep the parts of the `sunday` other than the `flag` property. Also, actually we don't need to make a copy with:

```
const resultsRooms = [ 
     ...this.state.results[0].rooms ];
```

Since we don't mutate it, with `map` we are creating a new array. So, here is the last version:

```
const rooms = results[0].rooms.map((room, roomIndex) => 
   ( { ...room, sunday: {...room["sunday"], flag: true } } )
);
```

This part is OK, we don't mutate the state but if you use `forEach` on `results` you mutate the original data. Don't do it.

Here is a concise and maybe a cleaner alternative without using `forEach`.

```
const newRooms = results[0].rooms.map( room =>
    ( { ...room, sunday: {...room["sunday"], flag: true } } )
  );

const newItem = { ...results[0], rooms: newRooms };
const newResults = Object.assign([], results, { 0: newItem } );
```

**Update after comments**

I used `Object.assign` here to replace the item without mutating the original array. When using React (also if you prefer to use with React, this applies to Redux also) we should avoid mutating our data, namely our state. So, when you plan to change something in the state you should do it in proper ways. Your question actually indicates that: "without mutating". This is why I used `Object.assign` here.

I could choose other methods like:

```
const newResults = results.slice();
newResults[ 0 ] = newItem;
```

or

```
const newResults = [ ...results ];
newResults[ 0 ] = newItem;
```

Those are ok **just for replacing the item as a whole**. What do I mean here? `slice` and `spread syntax` does not create deep copies, they just do shallow copies. If you change a property of an object in the newly created array, the original one also mutates. This also applies to objects when we change nested properties. Actually, original source is objects here.

Here is an example array:

```
const arr = [
  { id:1, name:"foo" },
  { id:2, name:"bar" },
  { id:3, name:"baz" },
];
```

and an example item to change for index 2 (last item here);

```
const newItem = { id: 100, name: "change" };

const newArr = [ ...arr ];
arr[ 2 ] = newItem;
```

This is ok since we change a whole object here. Let's see:

```js
const arr = [
  { id:1, name:"foo" },
  { id:2, name:"bar" },
  { id:3, name:"baz" },
];

const newItem = { id: 100, name: "change" };

const newArr = [ ...arr ];
newArr[ 2 ] = newItem;

console.log("new array", newArr );
console.log( "original array", arr );
```

Original one does not change. But if we do this:

```
newArr[ 2 ].id = 100; // ie, we only want to change the id, right?
```

Let's see:

```js
const arr = [
  { id:1, name:"foo" },
  { id:2, name:"bar" },
  { id:3, name:"baz" },
];

const newArr = [ ...arr ];
newArr[ 2 ].id = 100;

console.log("new array", newArr );
console.log( "original array", arr );
```

So, our original array also changed. Mutation! If you don't change any property like this you can choose one of all three alternatives. But if you change a property you should think something better.

```js
const arr = [
  { id:1, name:"foo" },
  { id:2, name:"bar" },
  { id:3, name:"baz" },
];

const newArr = Object.assign( [], arr, { 2: { ...arr[ 2 ], id: 100 } } );


console.log("new array", newArr );
console.log( "original array", arr );
```

Duh! :) Maybe there are better ways of doing this :) In any case, be very careful about mutating the state.

Just with an object:

```js
const obj = { 
  user: {
    id: 1,
    name: "foo",
  }
};
const newObj = { ...obj }
newObj.user.id = 1000

console.log( "new object", newObj );
console.log( "original object", obj );
```

Ok, this is enough for an explanation :)

> Thank you for the answer. I am a bit confused, am I supposed to set
>   the state as follows: this.setState({ results: newResults });

Yes.

> also what if i want to change the state of all results array rooms 
>   results[0],results[1],results[2] .....

Come on, you have a great tool here :) `map`

```
const newResults = results.map( item => {
  const newRooms = item.rooms.map( room =>
    ( { ...room, sunday: {...room["sunday"], flag: true } } )
  );
  const newItem = { ...item, rooms: newRooms };

  return newItem;
})
```

First, we map the `results`, for each item, we map `rooms` and change the data, return the new item. So in the end, we get a new array where all its items changed, but again without any mutation.

I suggest playing a little bit with `map`, `filter` and maybe `reduce` methods. Also looking for `spread syntax` or if you prefer `Object.assign` is a plus.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am a bit confused, am I supposed to set the state as follows: this.setState({ results: newResults });  Also can you explain me Object.assign, why do i need it

Comment: also what if i want to change the state of all results array rooms results[0],results[1],results[2] .....